# Search: Only show site URL for retrieved documennt

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, search, search-results, display-template

My customer has site collection with a vast amount of subsites, which in turn contain documents, lists and the like.
Now my customer wants to find for example a document from any of those subsites, but instead of having the URL to the documents only the URL of the containing subsite should be displayed.
Is there a build-in way of doing so or do I have to create a Display Template and use custom script to achieve this goal?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the "SPWebUrl" managed metadata property to get the subsite url. In the display template instead of link url use above mentioned property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understood you correctly there is no other way than to define a custom Display template?

Comment: creating new display template will be the best solution.